# Group by a range of numbers Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have a list of numbers in a python data frame and want to group these numbers by a specific range and count. The numbers range from 0 to 20 but lets say there might not be any number 6 in that case I want it to show 0.

dataframe column looks like

```
|points| 
   5
   1
   7
   3
   2
   2
   1
   18
   15
   4
   5
```

I want it to look like the below

```
range | count
1         2
2         2
3         1
4         1
5         2
6         0
7         ...
8
9...
```

Comment: `df.value_counts` and then append the required zeros

Comment: @Dan how would I do this?

Comment: Give it a try yourself first - let's see some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate through the input lines and fill up a dict with the values.
All you have to do then is count...

```py
import collections

#read your input and store the numbers in a list
lines = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
  lines = [int(line.rstrip()) for line in f]

#pre fill the dictionary with 0s from 0 to the highest occurring number in your input.
values = {}
for i in range(max(lines)+1):
  values[i] = 0

# increment the occurrence by 1 for any found value
for val in lines:
    values[val] += 1

# Order the dict:
values = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(values.items()))
print("range\t|\tcount")
for k in values:
  print(str(k) + "\t\t\t" + str(values[k]))
```

repl: https://repl.it/repls/DesertedDeafeningCgibin

Edit:

a slightly more elegant version using dict comprehension:

```py
# read input as in the first example
values = {i : 0 for i in range(max(lines)+1)}
for val in lines:
  values[val] += 1

# order and print as in the first example
```

Comment: How do I add in the other numbers missing from the list

Comment: ah you want those to. that actually makes it easier.

Comment: take a look now, does this help you?